# Plotting Complex Parametric Curves

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, parametrization

I have to plot out by hand the following curve
$z(t) = 3+ie^{it}$ for $0\leq t \leq \pi$

I know that circles in $\mathbb{C}$ can be parameterized as $z(t) = c + re^{it}$ where the circle has radius $r$ and is centered at $c$. This parametrization starts at $c+r$ and traces the circle out in the counterclockwise

From this, it is telling me that it is centered at $3$ and has a radius of $i$ but a circle can't have a radius of $i$. Can someone help me clarify this and explain if there is another way to plot it?

Comment: it is a circle of radius $|i|.$  That $i$ is complex an not real, will influence where the circle starts and ends, that is, where is $z(0).$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $i=e^{i \frac{\pi}{2}}$.